# Native browser autocomplete does not work for ReactJS controlled inputs in IE11, Firefox, MS Edge (works in chrome ony)

Tags: reactjs, forms, internet-explorer, firefox, autocomplete

I need to make work native browser form autocomplete for controlled inputs in React in all browsers (currently works in chrome only).

Code snippet below is forked from React Form doc. (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). I only added name attribute to input element. Full example with possibility to run at https://codepen.io/DChuhin/pen/ZNmdWj

So after doing steps in code pen:
1) input any value 
2) submit provided value
3) start entering same value after submit: in chrome I can see my previous input as autocomplete option, but in other browsers it doesn't work.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input name="testName" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

After investigating this, I've found that the problem is that browsers (except chrome) do not save input value as autocomplete option if visible value on page is equal to value attribute in html (in inspector) at the moment when form is submitted (it is considered like user did not enter any input). But as React controlled component idea is to keep value attribute always up to date (it is always equal to the value on page) this behavior leads to the problem that there is no way to store values for autocomplete.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to debug the code, whether it displays some javascript error? Besides, from [this article](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features), we can see that the react support for Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 requires polyfills, please make sure you have added the polyfills.

Comment: If there is no error, I think perhaps this is the browser behaviours, the google browser might be auto store the value. If you want to implement autocomplete function, I suggest you could refer to [this sample](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/forms/autocomplete/) and [this article](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete),you could define an array to store the autocomplete options, then using the autocomplete plugin to display the options. when you click the submit button, you could get the textbox value and check whether the array contains the value, if not, insert it into the array.

Comment: I was able to confirm your problem in my React app. As soon as I make an input controlled, it no longer saves autocomplete entries in Firefox.

Comment: I came across this issues today. And can confirm it happens in React's controlled component. If it's an uncontrolled component, it's fine.